# Jenkins doesn't build on first push event, triggered by gitlab

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, webhooks

I configured my gitlab to send a webhook to jenkins on each push event.

My problem is, that jenkins don't start to build for the **first push event of a branch**, i.e. if I create a new branch.

My command is this:

> git checkout -b foo ; git push --set-upstream origin foo

And the webhook message looks like that:

```
{
    "before": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "after": "30677c0db88ea188e501199ba33f05df06dba4fc",
    "ref": "refs/heads/foo",
    "user_id": 4,
    "user_name": "Sascha Schimke",
    "project_id": 3,
    "repository": {
        "name": "...",
        "url": "git@gitlab...",
        "description": "",
        "homepage": "http://gitlab..."
    },
    "commits": [],
    "total_commits_count": 0
}
```

I would expect the jenkins to start building my project, but it does not.
The 2nd push works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which URL is your hook pointing to? Are you using the GitLab hook plugin, or the Git plugin? Do you see anything in the Jenkins log when the push happens?

Comment: @DrSchimke Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: @csnate Not yet. I was able to ignore that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug on the GitLab Jenkins plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/238

Upgrading to 8.6.4 (using the Docker images) fixed the issue for me.